# ProgressBar with background images

Tags: java, android, progress-bar, seekbar, android-seekbar

I want to create a progress bar[ProgressBar screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUCp6.png) like given image where the star image should reduce based on time(every second). So,Please guide me how to do? I am using the handler for countdown timer
**timeString* we are getting it from different class**

```
  String timestring = getIntent().getStringExtra("ageintent");
        timereceived = Integer.parseInt(timestring);
        seekbar.setMax(timereceived);
        seekbar.setClickable(false);
        timereceived--;
        time.setText(String.valueOf(timereceived));
        back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });
        handler = new Handler();
        run = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int seconds = Integer.parseInt(timeseconds.getText().toString());
                int timechange = Integer.parseInt(time.getText().toString());
                seekbar.setProgress(seconds);
                seconds--;
                timeseconds.setText(String.valueOf(seconds));
                if (seconds == 0 && timechange == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(Naughty_Step.this, "Your punishment is completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    soundplayer.start();
                    timereceived--;
                } else if (seconds == 0) {
                    timeseconds.setText("59");
                    timechange--;
                    seekbar.setProgress(seconds);
                    time.setText(String.valueOf(timechange));
//                    int min= Integer.parseInt(time.getText().toString());
//                    seekbar.setProgress(min);
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                } else {
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                }

            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(run, 1000);


    }
```

Comment: what is stopping you?

Comment: No, thank you. At least show some effort when asking a question, to at least google the code for it.

Comment: Searched for it but could not find the required answer.

Comment: When we are count downing the time the star image in the above screen not decreasing... So, can you please assist me for that.

Comment: You should set the progress to your seekbar.

Comment: set thumb as star image. and for reduce the progress (100 - ((currenttime-starttime) * 100 / total_time)).

Comment: I have written like this mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(30000,1000)

Comment: Please check my updated code above.

Answer (score 1):

Try below -

```
    SeekBar seekBar1 = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
    drw = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    seekBar1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new yourListener());

private class yourListener implements SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {

        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {


                    iSize = 100 - progress;


            tv.setText(String.valueOf(new Integer(progress)));   
            drw = resize(drw);
            seekBar.setThumb(drw);
        }

        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}

        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}

    }


    //Reduce size of seekbar 
    private Drawable resize(Drawable image) {
        Bitmap b = ((BitmapDrawable)image).getBitmap();

        Bitmap bitmapResized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, iSize, iSize, false);
        return new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmapResized);
    }
```

Comment: I will  be try it.

Comment: This did not worked for me please see that the seekbar should move from right to left.

Comment: Please check my updated code above.

Answer (score 0):

Add this as inner class of your activity or fragment need progressbar reduce.

```
class CounterClass extends CountDownTimer {
int totalDuration;
public CounterClass(long millisInFeature, long countDownInterval) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    super(millisInFeature , countDownInterval);     
    this.totalDuration =millisInFeature     
}

@Override
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     int progress =((millisUntilFinished * 100 / totalDuration))
     progressbar.setProgress(progress);
}

@Override
public void onFinish() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

oncreate() or event start

```
(new CounterClass(30000,1000)).start();
```